# Python sum data with the same name

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a .csv file which looks like this:

```
12/26/2022  AECIZ       516.09  536.37  652.42  528.71  510.65  658.19  566.92  740.25  695.88  574.17  567.22  386.42
12/26/2022  AECIZ       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
12/26/2022  AECO        657.94  597.16  575.53  545.27  558.24  587.9   627.29  653.44  577.64  528.35  556.93  675.62
12/26/2022  AECO        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
12/26/2022  AEP         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   198.5   350.5
12/26/2022  AEP         -2852.5 -1585.21    -1201.32    -634.19 -1147.48    -1227.88    -773.48 -633.44 -407.06 -150.65 0   0
12/26/2022  ALTE        187.74  227.4   301.39  252.88  323.56  290.2   314.86  315.52  272.74  241.95  280.06  269.78
12/26/2022  ALTE        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
12/26/2022  ALTW        760.49  682.41  553.86  405.95  302.72  281.95  359.79  439.3   268.91  14.16   0   0
12/26/2022  ALTW        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -146.06 -238.28
```

I would like to combine the rows with the same name by adding each element separately(starting from the 3rd column)

I don't really know how to do that as a new user of python, hope you can help me.

Alright, here is the code I have so far:

```
eco_inter = open("Economic_interchange_real.csv")
eco_change = open("Economic_interchange_combine.csv","w")
eco_inter_reader = csv.reader(eco_inter)
company_track = ['','']
new_line = {}
for list_line in eco_inter_reader:
    for date in dates:
        if (list_line[0] == date):
            if (list_line[1] == company_track[1]):
                eco_change.write(list_line[0]+','+list_line[1])
                for j in (range(12)):
                    new_line[j] = list_line[2+j]+company_track[2+j]
                    eco_change.write(','+new_line[j])
                eco_change.write("\n")
            else:
                company_track = list_line
eco_inter.close()
eco_change.close()
```

It indeed combine the same company with the same date, but the the data does not sum, only listed in each cell of the new csv file

BTW, dates is a list contains all the date as example shows in the first column

Comment: What did you try? By the way, I'd do that in [tag:awk].

Comment: If you want to attract good answers you should show us you have made an effort. Play around a little and post some code - we respond well to attempts, even if they don't work!

Comment: @Conduit: I just put my code, still a problem, no error, but not what I want for the data sum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you have to to is cast the string representation of your numbers to actual numbers.

```
new_line[j] = str(float(list_line[2+j]) + float(company_track[2+j]))
```

Currently you are just concatenating strings.  I'd also recommend using pandas if you can get it.

Comment: You are welcome. Though do take a look at pandas, all that code and even the nice code in the other answer could be done in one line

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary for grouping lines that have the same date and name:

```
combined = {} # (date, name) -> [values for each line with this date and name]
with open("Economic_interchange_real.csv", "r") as infile:
    for line in map(str.split, infile):
        date, name, numbers = line[0], line[1], map(float, line[2:])
        # setdefaut: add entry if it does not exist
        combined.setdefault((date, name), []).append(numbers)
```

Now, for each of those groups you can `zip` and `sum` all the values and write those lines to file:

```
with open("Economic_interchange_comb.csv", "w") as outfile:
    for key in combined:
        line = list(key) + map(sum, zip(*combined[key]))
        outfile.write("\t".join(map(str, line)) + "\n")
```

Output:

```
12/26/2022  AECO    657.94  597.16  575.53  545.27  558.24  587.9   627.29  653.44  577.64  528.35  556.93  675.62
12/26/2022  ALTW    760.49  682.41  553.86  405.95  302.72  281.95  359.79  439.3   268.91  14.16   -146.06 -238.28
12/26/2022  ALTE    187.74  227.4   301.39  252.88  323.56  290.2   314.86  315.52  272.74  241.95  280.06  269.78
12/26/2022  AECIZ   516.09  536.37  652.42  528.71  510.65  658.19  566.92  740.25  695.88  574.17  567.22  386.42
12/26/2022  AEP -2852.5 -1585.21    -1201.32    -634.19 -1147.48    -1227.88    -773.48 -633.44 -407.06 -150.65 198.5   350.5
```